# JSON data not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: UI]

Apparaently when I click my All movies button nothing shows up

```js
    $("#showMovies").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
          $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
         const rowText = "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
            $("#movies").append(rowText);
          });
        }
      });
    });
    $("#movieAdded").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
           idmovielist: 10,
           name: 'Bubble Gum',
           thumnail_path: 'yourieiri.jpg',
           description: 'Disturbing',
           year_released: '2007',
           language_released: 'french'
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
         const rowText = "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
            $("#movies").append(rowText);
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
    body {
      background: #20262E;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }

    #banner-message {
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 300px;
    }

    button {
      background: #0084ff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px 14px;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    #banner-message.alt {
      background: #0084ff;
      color: #fff;
      margin-top: 40px;
      width: 200px;
    }

    #banner-message.alt button {
      background: #fff;
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mycrud.js"></script>
    </head>
      <title>My Movies</title>
      <header>
        <h1>Movies</h1>
      </header>
      <body>
    <button id = "showMovies" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">All Movies</button>
    <button id = "movieAdded" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-targe="#exampleModal">
    Add
    </button>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
      <thead style="background-color:#ddd;" class="table-borderless">
        <tr>
          <th>idmovielist</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>thumnail_path</th>
          <th>description</th>
          <th>year_released</th>
          <th>language_released</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="movies"></tbody>
    </table>
```

When I run this code on jsfiddle all my data shows up on the tables and it is working fine but it does not show up on my web browser is something wrong with my html or javascript. Alos when I run my code on js fiddle one of my columns which is thumnail_path shows undefine.

Comment: You are running this page from file system and not from localhost server. Ajax is blocked by default by browsers when running from `file://` protocol. Use a localhost server for development

Comment: Open browser dev tools console (F12) . Should see a CORS warning message saying basically the same thing

Comment: @charlietfl when I open the console it is blank

Comment: Ok..might have some of the warnings turned off....but issue is the same

Comment: @charlietfl and how can I run this web page on a local host

Comment: @charlietfl where can I move my files to

Comment: Lots of ways to set up a localhost server on your computer. Do a web search and try various approaches until you find what you like

Comment: @charlietfl I have a localhost already running with my json file tho

Comment: OK...so open the html page using that localhost to serve it

Comment: @charlietfl so connect the file in which I have my local host on to my html file

Comment: @charlietfl http://localhost:3000/movielist this is the data in which I want to spit out on my webpage front end

Comment: Ok...but you want your html page to be on locahost:3000 also. Not loaded direct from your C Drive using file/open

Comment: @charlietfl can you show me an example I am quite confused

Comment: You need to be able to go to localhost:3000/index.html. Then ajax will be on same origin

Comment: @charlietfl you mean on my folder

Comment: @charlietfl you have google chat or something in which I could share you my screen

Comment: @charlietfl how can I include index.html in my localhost

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing how you set localhost server up.

Comment: @charlietfl http://localhost/UI%20CRUD/

Comment: @charlietfl so I put my html in the local host but its it still not running

Answer (score -2):

I believe you forgot to close the `<tr>` tags in ajax

Comment: It will automatically be closed.